# How to filter events from fabric8 sharedIndexInformer by labels?

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am on fabric8 kubernetes client v6.8.0 and initializing a sharedIndexInformer for a CRD like this:

```
SharedIndexInformer<MyResource> informer =
                sharedInformerFactory.sharedIndexInformerFor(MyResource.class, 30 * 1000L);
informer.addEventHandler(myEventHandler);
```

I only want to receive events from resources with certain labels.

This seemed straightforward in earlier version of the client, with label selection being one of the arguments in `sharedIndexInformerFor`.

```
SharedIndexInformer<MyResource> informer =
                    sharedInformerFactory.sharedIndexInformerFor(
MyResource.class, 
myLabelSelector,
30 * 1000L);
```

How to achieve this in v6.8.0+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more fine grained control over informers filtering, you can use the `inform()` method available on Resource DSL:

```java
SharedIndexInformer<MyResource> informer = client.resources(MyResource.class)
  .inNamespace("default")
  .withLabel("app", "test-operator")
  .inform(myEventHandler, 30 * 1000L);
```

Comment: If I don't want to observe a particular namespace, just ignoring inNamespace should be fine right? My initial tests show its picking up the namespace from the service account when I don't add inNamespace.

Comment: Default behavior is to pick namespace configured in your kube context or mounted ServiceAccount. You can use `inAnyNamespace()` in place of `inNamespace` to enforce no namespace